# API key not defined?

Tags: javascript

Error as follows:

```
    /home/runner/CrowdedMajesticRouter/index.js:3
    let apiKey,cJhlPVSd5-wzJ0iOv;

    ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'
```

```
let apiKey,
cJhlPVSd5-wzJ0iOv;   

let search = (term, location) => {
  return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=${term}&location=${location}`, {
    headers:  {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`
    }
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(jsonResponse => {
    if (jsonResponse.businesses) {
      console.log(jsonResponse.businesses)

    }

  });
}

search('Mexican', 'Los Angeles')
```

If the code is corrected as follows:

```
let apiKey = cJhlPVSd5-wzJ0iOv;

let search = (term, location) => {
  return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=${term}&location=${location}`, {
    headers:  {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`
    }
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(jsonResponse => {
    if (jsonResponse.businesses) {
      console.log(jsonResponse.businesses)

    }

  });
}

search('Mexican', 'Los Angeles')
```

then the error is:

```
ReferenceError: cJhlPVSd5 is not defined
    at /home/runner/CrowdedMajesticRouter/index.js:3:14
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:131:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:156:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js
```

Per yelp: /businesses/search
This endpoint returns up to 1000 businesses based on the provided search criteria. It has some basic information about the business. To get detailed information and reviews, please use the Business ID returned here and refer to /businesses/{id} and /businesses/{id}/reviews endpoints.

Note: at this time, the API does not return businesses without any reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted we can see you didn't declare your variable.

```
let apiKey 
somekey;
```

It should be

```
let apiKey, somekey;
```

or

```
let apiKey;
let somekey;
```

That's why you're getting the `ReferenceError`;

@Edit
Now I see

```
let apiKey,
cJhlPVSd5-wzJ0iOv;
```

It should be

```
let apiKey = 'cJhlPVSd5-wzJ0iOv';
```

No idea why you're trying separate it by comma.

Comment: The key does not seem to be accepted because of yelp addition of a hyphen in between the key. The key is formatted as: 12314-zx81 but i receive a '''SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-''''


Comment: Paste your whole code as it is, just replace your key with some another string. It's hard to be precise when you just cut out a part of code and replacing it with `<---`.

Comment: I think the correct way to declare a string would be `let apiKey = 'cJhlPVSd5-wzJ0iOv';`. With `let apiKey = cJhlPVSd5-wzJ0iOv;` the code asks for the difference between the variable `cJhlPVSd5` and the variable `wzJ0iOv` which both do not exist.

Comment: @BurningKarl you're right, forgot about quotes ^^. Gonna edit.